# How to feed git credentials into Jenkins pipeline steps such that any shell/terraform code can do a git clone while running the script

Tags: github, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, terraform

I have created a Jenkins pipeline that clones terraform code from my git repo (main_repo). The terraform templates further pull the code modules from another git repo (module_repo).

Now, I have added credentials to Jenkins and could clone both git repositories through 'checkout'.   However, when I run "terraform init" in my main_repo which contains the templates that does git clone on the module_repo, I see git clone failing.  Seems like the git credentials are not fed into the 'step' so that they can be used while doing the "terraform init". Is there a way we can feed the credentials into the 'steps' so that they can be used inside the code?

Here is how my code repo looks:

```
stage/
    dev/
       /user.tf
          module "my_module" {
              source = "git::ssh://git@wwwin-github.com/my-ops/ops_user.git"
          }
```

```
   stages {
        stage('First') {
            steps {
                checkout([
                    $class           : 'GitSCM',
                    branches: [[name: '*/master']],
                    userRemoteConfigs: [[
                      credentialsId: '#my cred',
                      name         : 'master',
                      url          : '#my_repo'
                    ]]
                ])
                checkout([
                    $class           : 'GitSCM',
                    branches: [[name: 'master']],
                    userRemoteConfigs: [[
                      credentialsId: '#my cred',
                      name         : 'master',
                      url          : '#my_module_repo'
                    ]]
                ])
                script {
                    def Tf = tool name: 'Terraform'
                }
                sh 'terraform --version'
            }
        }

        stage('Second') {
            steps {
                dir('stage/dev')
                        {
                            sh 'terraform init'
                        }
```

The First stage is successful and I could clone the repos.  But when I run "terraform init" inside stage/dev which contains a terraform template that does git clone from module_repo,  is failing.

I tried feeding the git credentials inside the 'dir' which didn't help either

```
stage('Second') {
            steps {
                dir('stage/dev')
                        {
                   git  url: '#my moduel repo',
                        credentialsId: '#My cred',
                        branch: 'master'
                   sh 'terraform init'
                }
```

This looks like a generic use-case, any suggestions on how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Try to use [SSH Agent plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SSH+Agent+Plugin): `sshagent(credentials: ['YourCredentialsId']){ sh 'terraform init' }`

Comment: I couldn't try your approach. I worked around it by copying the content to S3 and sourcing it from S3 instead of git.